# Case in Select query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement

Below is my SQL with a case statement.

```
select 
    a.AssociationClubNumber,
    case a.AssociationClubNumber
        when NULL then 'NA'
        when '' then 'NA'
        else a.AssociationClubNumber
    end as 'AssociationClubNumber'
from 
    [dbo].[Customer] a
```

If `a.AssociationClubNumber` is `NULL` or `""`, then the `CASE` should return the string "NA".

I tried few different combinations but somehow it's not executing.

Comment: Case when AssociationClubNumber is null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other form of `case` -- with explicit comparisons:

```
select c.AssociationClubNumber,
       (case when c.AssociationClubNumber is null or 
                  c.AssociationClubNumber = ''
             then 'NA'
             else c.AssociationClubNumber
        end)  as new_AssociationClubNumber
from [dbo].[Customer] c;
```

You are using the simple `case`.  Even in the simple form, `NULL` can never match -- basically because `=` does not work with `NULL`.

Also notice:

- I fixed the table alias so it makes sense (as a table abbreviation) rather than an arbitrary letter.
- I changed the column alias so the two columns being returned are different.
- I removed the single quotes around the column alias.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Great!! it executed as desired. I would mark this accept once allowed. also Many Thanks for adding other notes. Once again Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

remove single quote from alias and use `is null`

```
 select a.AssociationClubNumber,
    Case a.AssociationClubNumber
    When is NULL THEN  'NA'  
    WHEN  '' then  'NA'
    ELSE a.AssociationClubNumber
    END  as AssociationClubNumber_val
    from [dbo].[Customer] a
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE [value] WHEN NULL THEN END` will never evaluate to true. You would have to use `CASE WHEN [value] IS NULL THEN 1 END`.

For what you have though, I would use:

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(AssociationClubNumber,'')'NA')
```